# Saving an integer value for later on an iPhone

Tags: objective-c

How do you save a value from a text feild so that can be saved and displayed later, on a differnt opening.

Comment: You need to say more about what you're doing here. Is this on a Mac? an iPhone? There are lots of places to save data; depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:10 forKey:@"high_score"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Answer (score -2):

In a file ?

http://www.csharphelp.com/2005/12/simple-text-file-operations-in-c/

Comment: FYI: Question is about Objective-C, not C#.